# Input de datas no SAS

Tags: data, sas

Por favor, tentei de várias formas inserir datas pelo input do SAS Enterprise Guide versão 7.1, porém de todas as formas o resultado sempre sai na forma numérica, segue um exemplo do código:

```
data work.family;
infile datalines;
input relation $ first_name $ birthdate: mmddyy10.;
cards;
son Frank 01/31/89
daughter June 12-25-87
brother Samuel 01/17/51
run;
```

Na variável *bithdate* a inclusão ou remoção dos dois pontos, ou a mudança no tamanho do formato sempre resultam na data em forma numérica e não date:

```
relation   first_name birthdate
son        Frank      10623
daughter   June       10220
brother    Samuel     -3271
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente essa a sua dúvida, mas basta informar o FORMAT.

Exemplo:

```
data work.family;  
infile datalines;  
input relation $ first_name $ birthdate: mmddyy10.;  
format birthdate DDMMYY8.;  
cards;  
son Frank 01/31/89  
daughter June 12-25-87  
brother Samuel 01/17/51  
run;
```